# Midrash on commandments for non-Jews

Tags: gentiles, midrash, mitzvah, yetziat-mitzrayim

Note: I had recalled seeing this or a similar question somewhere on the site but couldn't find it.

There's a midrash that appears in two versions (that I know of), one in [Midrash Tehillim 21:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Tehillim.21.1?vhe=OYW&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi):

> "...אמר רבי חנינא אין מלך המשיח בא אלא ליתן לאומות העכו"ם שש מצות. כגון סוכה ולולב ותפילין. אבל ישראל למדין תורה מן הקדוש ברוך הוא שנאמר (שם נד יג) וכל בניך למודי ה'. ולמה בשביל (ישעיה יא י) אליו גוים ידרושו..."

Translation: "...Said Rabbi Chanina: "The King Messiah doesn't come but to give the idolatrous nations six commandments. Such as Sukkah, Lulav and Tefillin. But Israel study Torah from the Holy One, Blessed Is He, as it says (Isaiah 54:13) "And all your children shall be disciples of the LORD." And why? In order for (Isaiah 11:10) "Nations shall seek his counsel"..."

And the other version in [Yalkut Shimoni on Nach, 682](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.682.1?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "...אמר רבי חנינא אין מלך המשיח בא אלא ליתן לאוה"ע שתי מצות כגון סוכה ולולב. אבל ישראל כלם למדין תורה מן הקב"ה שנאמר וכל בניך למדי ה', ולמה, בשביל אליו גוים ידרושו..."

Translation: "...Said Rabbi Chanina: "The King Messiah doesn't come but to give the nations of the world two commandments, such as Sukkah and Lulav. But Israel will all study Torah from the Holy One, Blessed Is He, as it says: "And all your children shall be disciples of the LORD." And why? In order for (Isaiah 11:10) "Nations shall seek his counsel"..."

I was wondering on the choice of commandments in this midrash. All commandments mentioned - Sukkah, Lulav and Tefillin - are זכר ליציאת מצרים commandments - in remembrance of the Exodus. In what way would they be relevant to the nations of the world, who didn't go through the Exodus?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zechariah.14.16-19?lang=bi

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avodah_Zarah.3a.10?lang=bi